# jquery FullCalendar - Event re-sizing from its end date limit does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using Jquery FullCalendar.

Here is the link of calender I am using : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I want to resize an event by clicking on its end date limit (for example midnight and I want to resize it to 10pm), but in that case it doesn't work. The bottom limit of the event stays down. I think that there is a conflict with an element of the lower part of the calendar, but I can't find it.

Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Hey user, can you provide the relevant code that you are using in the calendar?

Comment: I found a solution so I don't know if it is a bug or not.. I have to take the lower part of the event and to go up rather high so that the movement of resizing is taken into account. It is strange but it works !